# django - get() returned more than one topic and filter doesn't work

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, filter, get

I have a problem with get() in Django. To wit I have such function:

```
  try:
      sth = Object.objects.get(t=request.GET.get('data'))
      if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = ObjectSerializer(sth)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I got error:

```
get() returned more than one Object -- it returned 2!
```

So I have swapped get for filter:

```
sth = Object.objects.filter(t=request.GET.get('data'))
```

But now I get error:

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `data` on serializer `ObjectSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'data'.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your top line of code (that looks like it would produce the error) doesn't actually use `get`, so please try to update to include an [mcve]

Comment: As the error says, you have more than one item in your database that matches the value of `data`. So you need to determine what you actually want to happen in this case. Do you want to serialize multiple items? Or do you actually want a single item - in which case you're going to need to have some way of determining which one you want. Is there another field you can use to filter on?

Comment: I want to return all items from table that match the value of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple specify many=True when creating a serializer from queryset.

```
  sth = Object.objects.filter(t=request.GET.get('data'))
  if request.method == 'GET':
      serializer = ObjectSerializer(sth, many=True) 
      return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: When I add `many=True` I get `Cannot resolve keyword 'many' into field. Choices are: ... `